# PHP QR Code Generator with SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, qr-code

I would like to use the results of a MYSQL query and generate a batch of QR Codes have the following php script via PhpQrCode. What I need is simply display the list of barcodes generated on HTML page. This is what I wrote so far:

```
<?php

include "qrlib.php";
require "conf/config.php";

            $con = mysql_connect(DBSERVER,DBUSER,DBPASS);
            mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $con); 
            $barcodes = mysql_query( "SELECT Description FROM dbo_sensorsandparts ORDER BY ID ASC");



while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($barcodes))
{

echo "<html>";

echo "<img src="; 

QRcode::png ($row['Description']);
echo ">";
}
?>
```

The query is correct since I tested it out but I only get a blank page with a sort of broken image. Can someone help me as to what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks

SOLVED as follows:

```
<?php    
require "conf/config.php";

            $con = mysql_connect(DBSERVER,DBUSER,DBPASS);
            mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $con); 
            $barcodes = mysql_query( "SELECT Description FROM dbo_sensorsandparts ORDER BY ID ASC");



    //set it to writable location, a place for temp generated PNG files
    $PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    //html PNG location prefix
    $PNG_WEB_DIR = 'temp/';

    include "qrlib.php";    

    //ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
    if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
        mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);


   $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'label.png';


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($barcodes))


{
  $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'label'.$row['Description'].'.png';

        QRcode::png($row['Description'], $filename); 

        echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>'; 
echo $filename;   

    }    

 ?>
```

Comment: Split your task into subtasks and solve them one after another. Then when you're in stuck solving something more specific - try to ask again. A first task, for example, might be to learn what `img src` accepts.

Comment: i could bet, *QRcode::png()* doesnt return a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as follows:

```
<?php    
    require "conf/config.php";

                $con = mysql_connect(DBSERVER,DBUSER,DBPASS);
                mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $con); 
                $barcodes = mysql_query( "SELECT Description FROM dbo_sensorsandparts ORDER BY ID ASC");



        //set it to writable location, a place for temp generated PNG files
        $PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

        //html PNG location prefix
        $PNG_WEB_DIR = 'temp/';

        include "qrlib.php";    

        //ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
        if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
            mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);


       $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'label.png';


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($barcodes))


    {
      $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'label'.$row['Description'].'.png';

            QRcode::png($row['Description'], $filename); 

            echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>'; 
    echo $filename;   

        }    

     ?>
```

I have stored the PNGs as files via variable $filename.

Answer (score 1):

To render the image in the html page, hold the returned QRcode image in a location and then specify it as a link in **src** attribute of `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If `QRcode::png` returns the raw image data, use data URIs to display:

```
$qr_code = base64_encode(QRcode::png ($row['Description']));

$src = 'data: image/png;base64,'.$qr_code;

echo '<img src="', $src, '">';
```

Comment: With the below code I am getting just one QR Code displayed ..`code` <?php

include "qrlib.php";
require "conf/config.php";
        
   $con = mysql_connect(DBSERVER,DBUSER,DBPASS);
   mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $con); 
   $barcodes = mysql_query( "SELECT Description FROM dbo_sensorsandparts ORDER BY ID ASC");
   
   
   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($barcodes))
{

$qr_code = base64_encode(QRcode::png ($row['Description']));

$src = 'data: image/png;base64,'.$qr_code;

echo '<img src="', $src, '">';


}
?> `code`

Comment: One image or multiple images but all the same qr code?

Comment: it just displays one QR image

Comment: So only one output? Are you sure the query is returning multiple rows? And if my solution worked, a thanks and upvote would be nice. I didn't sign on for debugging your whole script.

Comment: thanks for your help - yes the query returns multiple rows since I have tried it via a simple echo statement and it displays the correct results.

Comment: Is the loop completing? Is there anything in the error log?

Comment: many thanks for pointing out the error log. I have the following:[30-Jan-2015 09:55:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\tpm_dev\phpqrcode\qrimage.php:36) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tpm_dev\phpqrcode\qrimage.php on line 35

[30-Jan-2015 09:55:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\tpm_dev\phpqrcode\qrmask.php on line 195
I have thousands from the first warning because it seems that it is referring to each record....

Comment: what is actually returned by `QRcode:png()` ? Looking at the documentation, it's not clear at all whether it returns raw png or if it handles output to browser. If it's the latter, then you have to take a different approach.

Comment: I solved the problem myself - see edited code above. There was really no need to downgrade my points - i was only asking for direction !